# MongoDB - What's the best way to go about querying this data without using full-text

Tags: php, mongodb, full-text-search

I currently receive a data feed from a company nightly with ~5 million vehicle records. I recently had to move my MongoDB off one host to another. The only downside is, the new host does not allow full-text searching yet.

The data I receive looks similar to this...

```
{
    Year: 2004,
    Make: 'Chevrolet',
    Model: 'Impala',
    Trim: 'LS',
    ...
}
```

Previously, a user would type in a text box what they're looking for... for example: '2004 Chevrolet Imapala' and I would parse out the date and then run a full-text search using the remainder of the string.

However, now - I seem to be stuck with ideas as to how I can accurately return results to a user without having full-text search available.

Would there possibly be a way to auto-create a "tags" field in MongoDB?

For example...

```
{
    Year: 2004,
    Make: 'Chevrolet',
    Model: 'Impala',
    Trim: 'LS',
    tags: {
        'Chevrolet','Impala','LS'
    }
    ...
}
```

And then based on what they type, return the most relevant results?

Thank you for any help and/or suggestions you may have.

Comment: You should use a full text search engine like Solr or ElasticSearch rather than trying to force it into MongoDb if you care about performance.

Comment: I am using the shared single node on MongoLab - and I don't believe I can get Solr or ElasticSearch will work.

Comment: Use the right tool for the right job. You'll probably exceed the shared-node usage if you do intensive text search-like queries, especially as you'll find you really need to use regular expressions.

Comment: No, mongodb will not auto-create the tags, but it's easy to create it by yourself, see this example (for doctrine): http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/cookbook/simple-search-engine.html

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by full-text search ? are you using lucene or Solr ?

since mongo 2.2 I think there's the aggregate framework , here's the official documentation

```
http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/tutorial/aggregation-examples/
```

hope it'll help you !

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for the reply - previously I was able to query my entire 'vehicles' collection by issuing a db->command and then passing the query in to the search field.

For example:

db.collection.runCommand( "text", { search: '2004 Chevrolet Malibu' } )

But since I can't set textSearchEnabled=true - I have to resort to something else...

The aggregate framework looks close, but I am unsure how I would go about it